# Image Texture not showing

Tags: texturing

[image]

I'm having an issue with my image texture. I want the eye texture to show up on the flat surface I have selected but no matter what I do it never shows up.

Help please.

Comment: on your screenshot you are in Solid mode, have you tried in Rendered mode for example?

Comment: ......Well, I'm dumb.

Thanks for your help though lol.

Answer (score 1):

You are in *Solid* display mode, switch to *Rendered* display mode.

Comment: Thanks, I got that from the last guy who answered.